# Плавность анимации математического маятника

Tags: c++, qt, анимация

написал код для анимации математического маятника, проблема вся в обновлении, когда маятник возвращается в исходное положение.

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <cmath>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);  //Процедура отрисовки
    void update();
    void draw();

    private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer timer;

    const double Pi = 3.14;

    double phi = 0;

    double L;

    double dt = 0.01;
    double g = 9.81;
    double t =0;
    double w0;

    void ConnectSignalsWithSlots(); //Соединяем сигналы со слотами
    public slots:
    void btn_startClicked();        //Обработка нажатия на кнопку "Расчет"
    void btn_stopClicked();         //Обработка нажатия на кнопку "Остановить"
    void OnTimer();                 //Процедура, вызываемая таймером
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPainter>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ConnectSignalsWithSlots();
    timer.setInterval(60);
    timer.stop();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//Соединяем сигналы со слотами
void MainWindow :: ConnectSignalsWithSlots()
{
  QObject::connect(ui->btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btn_startClicked()));
  QObject::connect(ui->btn_stop, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btn_stopClicked()));
  QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(OnTimer()));
}

//Процедура отрисовки
void MainWindow :: paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  QPainter painter(this);
  double  lp = 200,   //Отображаемая длина маятника
          x0 = 640,
          y0 = 250,
          x = lp * sin(phi),       //Координаты
          y = lp * cos(phi);
  //Рисуем маятник
  QPen pen = painter.pen();
  pen.setWidth(2);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  painter.drawLine(x0, y0, x0 + x, y0 + y);
  painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(x0 + x, y0 + y), 10, 10);
}

void MainWindow:: update(){


}


//Обработка нажатия на кнопку "Расчет"
void MainWindow :: btn_startClicked()
{
  //Устанавливаем значения параметров
  L = ui->L_edit->toPlainText().toDouble();
  phi = ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText().toDouble();
  w0 = g/L;
  t = 0;

  //Запускаем таймер
  timer.start();
}

//Обработка нажатия на кнопку "Остановить"
void MainWindow :: btn_stopClicked()
{
  timer.stop();
}

//Процедура, вызываемая таймером
void MainWindow :: OnTimer()
{
    phi= sin(w0 * t + phi);
    t+=dt;

    this->repaint();
}
```

Comment: Что за проблема?

Comment: Анимация возвращения маятника в исходное состояние происходит слишком быстро

Comment: Я этого не вижу. Когда нажимается кнопка Стоп - таймер замирает и маятник, соответственно, тоже. Во время качания все происходит равномерно и симметрично. Поконкретнее можете сформулировать в чем проблема?

Comment: Каждый раз, когда вы нажимаете на кнопку "Расчет" вызывается метод btn_startClicked и маятник начинает качаться с начального угла Phi, который вы получаете из соответствующего textEdit

Comment: Короче, если отбросить фиговый интерфейс, то все ок :)

Comment: По коду да, а вот при запуске, маятник по часовой идёт с одной скоростью против часовой с другой.